# Pegar o tamanho de uma imagem

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagem

Há a possibilidade de pegar o tamanho via javascript de uma imagem externa ao meu diretório?

Por exemplo neste uso:

```
.divExterna{
background-image:url(http://www.backsite.com.br/datafiles/suite/escritorio/aplicativo/conteudo/album_fotografico/769.jpg),
height: seu_tamanho
}
```

Eu gostaria de pegar o seu tamanho para aplicar como altura da minha div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim (como tem o css estruturado) não vai dar porque a imagem está em background, pode no entanto fazer assim:

```css
div {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid yellow; /* isto é só para ver a div (altura/comprimento) */
 height: 150px;
}
img {
   height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://catracalivre.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/imagens-3D_11.gif">
</div>
```

Desta maneira a imagem vai ter sempre a altura (height) que definiu no elemento pai (div neste caso)

Comment: então a questão é que eu trabalho com mobiles, e gostaria que a div tivesse tamanho real da imagem, não teria como eu resgatar esse valor de alguma forma?

Comment: @Henricão, não com javascript... Não consegue navegar (que eu saiba) pelos diretorios e ver os conteudos, só consegue ver o tamanho de um elemento que exista no DOM. Mas isto funciona em mobile também, a imagem assim fica da altura que tu definires para a div

Comment: vou tentar aplicar isso, muito obrigado pelo feedback

Comment: De nada @Henricão